# How to create scrollbar in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, scroll

Recently, I've been doing some work on a personal project. The thing is that now, I need to create a widget with the scroll bars in a mainWindow.
But i do not know how!!!
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QScrollArea` which provides a scrolling view onto another widget. It is used to display the contents of a child widget within a frame. If the widget exceeds the size of the frame, the view can provide scroll bars so that the entire area of the child widget can be viewed.

An example:

```
 QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
 QImage image("happyguy.png");
 imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

 QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
 scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
 scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get compile errors? or you can not see scrollbars?

Comment: i can't see scrollbar

Comment: can i have your email?i want to send image for you about my question

Comment: You can see my email in my profile. You can not see the scrollbars because the size of your widget is not larger than the size of the frame for QScrollArea. Try to set a fixed size for your widget like myWidget->setFixedSize(2000,2000);

Comment: i can't find your email!! i have lenker error

Comment: i did it but i didn't see scroll bar..i tried it with designer also i didn't see scrollbar

Comment: did you try to set the size of your widget larger than the frame of QScrollArea?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not adding QScrollArea to your main window. I updated the answer.

Comment: i have a mainwindow.i add scrollarea and scroll bar in it's ui. in .cpp i write  ui->scrollArea->setWidget(mywidget); i see scrollarea but i dont see scroll bar!

Comment: Try myWidget->setFixedSize(2000,2000); to resize your widget larger than the size of the frame for QScrollArea.

Comment: myWidget is a table that i set it (100,100) but also i dont see scrollbar!! :o

Comment: Do you want the scrollbars appear in your table? i.e. are you going to have a QTableView or QTableWidget which is scrollable?

Comment: nooo!!please say your email that i send a picture for you.because i cant send picture here